# What should be my input shape for the code below

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here i have a very simple regression code written with Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]],
               dtype="float32")
y_train = np.array([[-1,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]],
               dtype="float32")

loss = 'mean_squared_error'
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500)
```

When i run this code i get this error:

**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_24_input to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (11,)**

Now i know if i remove a pair of brackets from my x_train and y_train, the code will run fine, like this:

```
x_train = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
               dtype="float32")
```

But my question is, **how can i run this code with the same data shape?** What should be the **input_shape** so i don't get the error above?

Comment: Hello you've one feature _X_ so ut will be (1,) of course.

Comment: Hello `input_dim` is the number of dimensions of the features, in your caase in one feature so one dim.

Comment: ow can i run this code with the same data shape? @abdoulsn

Comment: As @y.selivonchyk written it, I executed it then it worked well.

Comment: As you can see he did removed one pair of brackets from the np.array. The shape is (1,) what if i want the shape to be (1,11)?

Comment: Check my answer. Use input_dim no input_shape with take care of MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you want to use your data format

So you've to  do this litle change on your layer `[tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=11, input_dim=11)]`. As you use `mean_squared_error`. Your output should be the same as your `inut_dim`, I set `units=11`.

Wrap up.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]], dtype="float32")
y_train = np.array([[-1,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]], dtype="float32")

loss = 'mean_squared_error'
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=11, input_dim=11)])

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500)
```

Comment: Your code is ok, but you have 11 units, which makes 11 neurons if I'm right, and for predicting i have to give (11,1) shape inputs again. But i want to use something like model.predict([8]).

Comment: You can add one more layer fir that.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you have 11 examples in x and y arrays. In order to train that each example has to be in a subarray of size 1:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
               dtype="float32")
y_train = np.array([-1,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19],
               dtype="float32")

x_train = np.asarray([[x] for x in x_train])
y_train = np.asarray([[x] for x in y_train])

loss = 'mean_squared_error'
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=500)
```

Comment: I know if i do it with single bracket it will work. But if i want my exact code to work (the code i've posted x_train and y_train with two brackets...) what should be the input size? for sure [1] is not working.

Comment: With your code x_train shape is (1,) what if i want the shape to be (1,11) like my first code? Then my input shape should be like what?

Comment: @Shahryar Keras expects a list of examples (for batching) and each example supposed to be in it's own array. If you want to feed a bunch of inputs as if your were feeding them as above than a single convolutional unit can do the trick, but for that you would probably need to feed shape [1, 1, 11] not [1, 11]